# Tkinter vs Linux (ubuntu/Mint) <KP_Enter> not enabled by default

Tags: linux, tkinter, bind

On Windows the events of the 'Return' key by default are already linked to the <KP_Enter> key. For example selecting a combobox item, or closing a mesagebox

Here I use Linux Mint x64 Cinnamon 20.2, based on Ubuntu. And the <KP_Enter> key is not linked to the events of the 'Return' key. Is this a **bug**? Or I need to do some configuration.

example if I try to select an item from the combobox with Enter, it works. But if I press <KP_Enter> (numeric enter) nothing happens

---

If this is a bug, where can I report it?

Comment: Can you find in the tkinter documentation where it says it should do this?  I see this: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html  (search for KP_Enter)

Answer (score 0):

Key Pad Enter (KP_Enter) does not work on Ubuntu. Let me know if you find an alternative.

This is the archived list of predefined events and it is listed. Again, if there is an alternative let us know.

https://web.archive.org/web/20190512164300id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-types.html

Comment: This does not seem to try and answer `Is this a bug?`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31654710)

Answer (score 0):

from my knowledge of free pascal programming

in windows : Enter(or return key) is mapped to one key VK_RETURN

in Linux : Enter is mapped to 2 keys

1. for keypad(numeric) to XK_KP_Enter
2. for left return XK_RETURN